# Astronomy's influence on astrology

Tags: astrology

Strong belief in relevance and effectiveness of astrology in ancient and modern India was/is used to fix suitable timings for events such as travel starting, thread ceremony, marriage,griha pravesam etc.

The experts in astrology of yore were the same as mathematicians and panchang computation scholars (e.g., Aryabhatta, Varahamihira).

Did they find significant correlation between astronomical timings and prediction of any significant turn of events / miraculous occurrences etc.? If so is there a textual reference to the actual events and predictions to reinforce people's trust at that time or later?

Was the Hindu/Indian acceptance of astrology due to pure respect to those jyothisham well versed and verified the correlation? Or they did not dare to oppose scholastic authority?

To me it feels jyothisham pundits would never have risked loss of their own reputation by talking and supporting astronomy and astrology in the same breath.. when only the former is/was directly verifiable.

In western society with same astronomical knowledge, astrology is generally not recognized as a science and did/does not gain much general social acceptance.

Comment: both are like light and shadow. astronomy is position of planets & starts. these positions affect the mind of people in a certain. what way that is, is described in astrology. In Sanskrit/Vedas, there is only 1 field - jyotisha, which deals with both. the latter is also directly verifiable if you meet the right astrologer (those who study it with devotion, unlike those who do it for money). Jyotisha is one of the 6 veda-angas. Take your jatakam to certain 'josiars' in Chennai without informing anything about your past, and verify it past yourself. I personally have and was amazed.

Comment: Charlatan astrologers of Kaliyuga had been responsible for bringing negative image of astrology just like fake babas control minds of people via media and thats why astrology is called pseudo science just like modern atheist scientific scholars reject the presence of soul. Astrology is Spiritual science which was revealed to lineage of sage Vashishta like BPHS, Astronomy is modern material science based upon calculations with modern equipments. Paramhansa Yogananda has discussed about true astrology in his book which he learnt from his guru. https://www.crystalclarity.com/yogananda/chapter-16/